# AFNetworking POST method call

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am new to `AFNetworking`. How can i execute the success and failure blocks of the following

```
NSMutableDictionary *rus = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[rus setValue:@"1211" forKey:@"id"];
[rus setValue:@"33" forKey:@"man"];
    [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://mysite.co/service.php" rus];
```

How to show the success or failure after executing the above code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

requestWithMethod does not actually complete the call, it just returns you an NSMutableURLRequest.  You need to take that request and make an AFHTTPRequestOperation.  You can set a success/failure block on this object and then run the start method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *rus = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[rus setValue:@"1211" forKey:@"id"];
[rus setValue:@"33" forKey:@"man"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://mysite.co/service.php" parameters:rus];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Code for success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Code for failure
}];
[operation start];
```

All that being said, are you using an outdated version of AFNetworking?  The method you're referencing is deprecated.

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                             URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(id)parameters
                                 error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

Above is the correct method to use.  You should pass in an error object.

Finally, an even easier way to accomplish what you're doing with AFNetworking 2.0 is below:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://mysite.co/service.php" parameters:rus success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Code for success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Code for failure
}];
```

Comment: I am using `AFNetworking 2`, but the parameters that i am passing are not read on the server. Therefore, i thought to encode it prior to sending.  How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *rus = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[rus setValue:@"1211" forKey:@"id"];
[rus setValue:@"33" forKey:@"man"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://mysite.co/service.php" parameters:rus success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://mysite.co/service.php" parameters:rus success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Code for success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Code for failure
}];
```

github's AFNetworking document

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking