# How to do post method in AFNetworking in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

This is my code. Now `afnetworking` totally changed to `nsurlsession` and first time i am using `afnetworking`.

```
-(void)responseRunning:(NSString *)url :(BOOL) method :(NSData *)data
{
    if(method)
    {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
//                NSLog(@"Error: this is error message %@", error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"this is response objectv %@%@", response,responseObject);
                [self responseCompleted:responseObject];
            }
        }];

        [dataTask resume];
    }
    else
    {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data progress:nil

         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             if (error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error: this is error message %@", error);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"this is response objectv %@%@", response,responseObject);
                 [self responseCompleted:responseObject];
             }
         }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }
}
```

first one is `response` method and thats working fine ,but while do post method i am struggling .

This is my code please help to find out the solution ...

```
output:


  Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:/modules/api/forgetpassword/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:/modules/api/forgetpassword/, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: You should have a look in the example project of AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: are you running on iOS9? have you conformed the URL query schemes? have you concerned to configure the application security protocol?

Comment: @Kishorekumar, which one is _no_?

Comment: i am using ios 9,but i didn't use any application security protocals @holex

Comment: @Kishorekumar, okay, so it is about time to dig yourself into those topics on iOS9, as that will present the solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi, Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790199/afnetworking-post-method-call/32793693#32793693

Answer (score 0):

since iOS9 initially you need to populate your `info.plist` file by the following values:

## the query schemes

which schemes you intent to open in your app, you can extend to this list with your custom URL schemes, if necessary:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>https</string>
</array>
```

## the transport security

which defines excuses for the app to receive response from any type of back-end:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

---

*NOTE: I personally **would not** recommend to bypass the official app transport security protocols for you and for your end-users safety, but obviously if you have no control of the back-end, you might not have too many other choices. if you can control the back-end I highly recommend to [read this documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) and make your server side secure enough for iOS9+.*

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating an Upload Task

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/upload"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
  //enter code here 
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
}
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

### Useful Links

https://www1.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/home/98-teaching/tutorials/540-ios14intro-client-server-communication

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

### Note: In Xcode 7

[image: Make sure that these added in Plist]

Comment: i didn't sent any images ,i like to send only text ,then how i have to do?